# Is it possible to set scala imports layout in editorconfig using IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, editorconfig

I want to set a rule for imports using `.editorconfig` for my scala project
the same as Java rule :

```
ij_java_imports_layout = *, |, javax.**, java.**, |, $*
```

Idea says property not supported:

```
ij_scala_imports_layout = *, |, javax.**, java.**, |, $*
```

I'm using: **IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)**

Is there any workaround maybe ?